# Owner of GoogleAds in My App

Tags: android, admob, apk, ads

Today i found my app distributed on some anonymous site. I downloaded it and decompiled it using apk tool.

How can i tell if ads being served in this apk are my ads. Is there any publisher id that i can get after decompiling app or any signature.

Ads used : Google Ads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create `AdMob` banner, you usually use something like this, which includes your personal code:

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "b12398345897ac32 <-- here's the code");
```

therefore if this code is the same as in the original application, ads are served for you, if not -- for someone else.

Comment: I think this code is converted to something else during compiling. I  am unable to find this code or something that replaced it. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @poster: This String literal like "b12398345897ac32" should be unchanged in the decompiled Java code. What have you found by grepping `"AdView"` in the decompiled code ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CP3RAPje . However i am unable to find this literal. I don't know where to look for it.

Comment: /smali/com/google/ads/GoogleAdView.smali is the google source related to Ads, you should search for _your own_ class where you create `AdView`, if this is really your application you should know the class name and also you should know your code, so you can easily grep the sources.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, there's another good way to check if your application was tampered with -- check the certificate the application file is signed with, if it's your certificate -- you may skip decompiling and stop worrying.